# Siderbar doesn't change screen using onTap()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem with the sidebar menu. In `MenuItem` onTap does not change the screen. What's wrong and how can I fix it? I think the problem is in `NavigationStates get initialState => HomePage (); (in sidebar_layout)` because it is always the HomePage set by default. I need `initialState` because otherwise `create: (context) => NavigationBloc (initialState),` gives error as it expects a parameter. How can I fix it all?

**This is the MenuItem**

```
MenuItem(
       icon: Icons.home,
       title: "HomePage",
       onTap: (){
         print("test");
         onIconPressed();
         BlocProvider.of<NavigationBloc> (context).add(NavigationEvents.HomePageClickedEvents);
       }
),
```

**This is the sidebar_layout**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:solaris/pages/homepage.dart';

import '../bloc.navigation_bloc/navigation_bloc.dart';
import 'sidebar.dart';

class SideBarLayout extends StatelessWidget {

  NavigationStates get initialState => HomePage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
        create: (context) => NavigationBloc(initialState),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, NavigationStates>(
              builder: (context, navigationState) {
                return navigationState as Widget;
              },
            ),
            SideBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is the navigation_bloc**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import '../pages/homepage.dart';
import '../pages/secondpage.dart';
import '../pages/thirdpage.dart';

enum NavigationEvents {
  HomePageClickedEvents,
  SecondPageClickedEvents,
  ThirdPageClickedEvents,
}

abstract class NavigationStates{}

class NavigationBloc extends Bloc<NavigationEvents, NavigationStates>{

  NavigationBloc(NavigationStates initialState) : super(initialState);

  @override
  NavigationStates get initialState => HomePage();

  @override
  Stream<NavigationStates> mapEventToState(NavigationEvents event)  async*{
    switch(event){
      case NavigationEvents.HomePageClickedEvents:
        yield HomePage();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.SecondPageClickedEvents:
        yield SecondPage();
        break;
      case NavigationEvents.ThirdPageClickedEvents:
        yield ThirdPage();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `@override   NavigationStates get initialState => HomePage();` because it's deprecated and
then in SidebarLayout you need to add to NavigationBloc constructor like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
        create: (context) => NavigationBloc(Home()),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<NavigationBloc, NavigationStates>(
                builder: (context, navigationStates) {
              return navigationStates as Widget;
            }),
            SideBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

check my Github, it will help you.
If it's helpful give me 'useful' https://github.com/3langn/ThisWillHelpYou